# Do you have to put extend in a sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, use-case, sequence-diagram

I wanted to know if you have to put an extend in a sequence diagram. Let's say I have a use case diagram for registration. I have included an extend which is re enter password. Does that have to be in a sequence diagram or do I not put it in?

Thanks

Comment: This is not because an UC extends other(s) that you to have to describe it (or its implementation ?) or not in a collaboration (may be shown through an SD). There is no link between the elements, It is like if you ask us "do I have to describe / show implementation of an UC when its name starts by the letter A". If that UC is important for you describe it, else no, like for any other UC.

Comment: There is an other problem, for me to (re) enter a password is probably not an extend but a preconditions of other(s) UCs, because you do not know when an extension occurs but the moment the password must be (re)enter is important.

Comment: @bruno My 3 problems again: Login is no use case...

Comment: @qwerty_so I still do not agree with you about that, a login is an interaction of a user and a system so a typical UC.

Comment: @bruno Nonsense, sorry. A use case describes an added value. Login is an activity (caused by a constraint) in an use case.

Comment: @qwerty_so so when you write the UCs for a cash machine you deliberately omit the UC allowing to enter the PIN number because it has no added value ... great

Comment: @bruno As I said: it's a constraint, not a use case. Tough to learn for a techie, I know.

Comment: @sqlcoder I encourage you to not take into account the remark of qwerty_so about _login_, he is 100% wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already [qwerty_so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60364451/3723423)'s excellent answer.  I'd nevertheless like to add some information:

- An UML diagram does not have to represent the full system with all the details. **YOU** decide what you want to show. Your model is your story to explain the design.
- Usually, some diagrams shows the big picture, and other diagrams focus on the relevant details. Because putting everything on one diagram makes it very difficult to read.
- The [UC diagram](https://www.ivarjacobson.com/sites/default/files/field_iji_file/article/use-case_2_0_jan11.pdf) shall focus on what matters to the user: browsing a catalog, purchasing a film, checkout the cart,... It should show things that the user is interested in. Personally, I don't know many users that are genuinely interested in entering or re-entering passwords.  Therefore it should not appear on an UC diagram (except if it's for school and the teacher was mislead in asking you to do so).
- The UC diagram should not represent the user interface.  [Ivar Jacobson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivar_Jacobson), the creator of UC, has repeated it many times and even documented it [in a book](https://books.google.be/books/about/The_Unified_Software_Development_Process.html?id=s1OdpwAACAAJ&redir_esc=y):  UC is not good for modelling user interface interactions; other techniques are more suitable.
- If you transform a UC into a class diagram or a sequence diagram, you probably would end up with [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-control-boundary).  So 1 UC would mean at least 2 participants in the sequence diagram.  2 UC means at least 4 participants.  It'd be already a very detailed diagram with many interactions.  Yes, you can.  But maybe it'll be more readble to have a first SD focusing on the real UC that add value for the user. A second SD may then focus on the detailed interactions for the re-entering of password, without showing all the details of the main SD.  Each SD would then be easier to digest.

Comment: But your answer is much more detailed :-) I'm often too lazy to repeat them... +1

Answer (score 1):

A SD is used to show a certain sequence of messages in a certain context. If you model a collaboration you tell in which context this collaboration happens. If your context is that where you re-enter the passwort then you show those messages happening there. If you context is the "sunny day" then you just skip that part.

There is no single SD for a system you design. There are as many SDs as you need to make clear how the system works.

Comment: my objective is to design a film system where you can browse and purchase films. Thats where the registration and login comes in. I added the re enter password as an extend in the use case diagram. Are you saying that it doesn't need to be added in a sequence diagram. Im not sure wether I should include it in or not.

Comment: Well, what should I say except the above? Add it if you need it. Leave it out if not. FWIW: Login is no UC at all. Anyhow.